# Automatically refreshing page data with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with a list of items for the user to complete in a queue. Items get added into the database, and I need this list to be updated and reflect those changes on a regular basis (perhaps every minute).

I don't want to add a meta refresh to the page, because I want to avoid reloading the page. I already have a function that updates the list via ajax, so I'd like to call this function every minute.

Once the page is initially loaded, how can I repeatedly call this function without doing a blocking javascript loop? Is there a way to pause the setInterval or something to allow the rest of the queue pool to execute?

I'm worried about this happening:

```
$('document').ready(function () { 
      setInterval( function() {
           updateList();
      }, 60000);
}
```

Comment: Remove `while(true)` loop as `setInterval` will execute `updateList` function at 1 mins interval, so you don't need the loop

Comment: You will probably also want to reduce your interval. Currently what you are doing is trying to start an infinite loop every 60 seconds.

Comment: I messed up the pseudo code, but I corrected it. I want to loop and execute the function every 60 seconds

Comment: Maybe a web socket would work here, e.g., `socket.io`?

Comment: __Remove `while(true)` loop__ even in your updated code. Read [WindowTimers.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)

Comment: You just need `setInterval(updateList, 60000);`

Comment: I dont think while(true) is required, because your code is executed once the DOM is ready,(document.ready)...So I suggest you to remove the while(true)

Comment: yeah long polling is kind of old school thing.and setInterval and ajax functions are already working asynchronously just removing the line of while(true) should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the while loop. I'll test out the setInterval and see how it behaves. I'd like to go the WebSocket route though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `while(true)` loop will indeed block the execution of all other scripts. [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) will not.

The ideal solution would be a web socket like [`socket.io`](http://socket.io). With this, you could have something as simple as

```
socket.on("add", function (msg) {
    addItem(msg);
}).on("removeItem", function (msg) {
    removeItem(msg);
})
```

Then, on your server, you could simply `socket.emit("messageType", msg);`. This would prevent you from having to constantly poll the server with AJAX.

However, if that is not possible, you can fix your code with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var updateInterval = setInterval(updateList, 60000);
    // to clear interval: clearInterval(updateInterval);
})
```

where `updateList` is your function to poll the server via AJAX and append whatever tasks are received to the page.

Comment: Thanks. This answer provides an immediate solution using just the setInterval code, as well as a (great) suggestion for the use of websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Summing up from the comments:

- You should get rid of `while(true)`, it is blocking the rest of the code.
- The `setInterval()` will be executed every 1min. anyway.

Note that after removing the  `while`, the `setInterval()` will not block the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following two:

`setTimeout(expression, timeout);` which executes the code/function once after the timeout. It is non blocking so you don't have to put it in a loop. You can call itself to make it execute infinitely.

```
function updateFunction() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //update the page here
    updateFunction();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Or you can use `setInterval(expression, timeout);` which executes the code/function in intervals, with the length of the timeout between them.

```
setInterval(function() {
  //update the page here
}, 1000);
```